# access value inside this.state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, prop

I have the following line of codes.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            trends_1: [
                { start: [parseFloat(props.ab), parseFloat(props.cd)], end: [parseFloat(props.wy), parseFloat(props.yz)], appearance: { stroke: "green" }, type: "XLINE" }
            ]
        };
    }
```

How can I access the value of `parseFloat(props.ab)` and `parseFloat(props.yz)`?

Comment: `this.state.trends_1.start`, it will be an array, so `let [ab, yz] = this.state.trends_1.start; console.log('ab = ', ab, ' yz = ', yz);`

Comment: I am calling it inside `return()`, okay, I will use `let` to declare them, but how can I access this array item directly? say `this.state.trends_1.start.ab`

Comment: nope not like that, start is an array not object, so you need to specify the index, value of ab will be on index 0 and yz will be on 1, so `this.state.trends_1.start[0]`, and `this.state.trends_1.start[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it with index position

```
this.state.trends_1[0].start[0]
this.state.trends_1[0].start[1]

this.state.trends_1[0].end[0]
this.state.trends_1[0].end[1]
```

Comment: i get an undefined result.

Comment: Ok what is the value of props.ab, props.cd, props.wy and props.yz in constructor?

Comment: they are timestamp: `ab = 1536038220000, cd = 1536046560000, wy= 1536038460000 and yz=1536050700000`.

Comment: It worked for me too when I tested in my local machine

Answer (score 1):

You have to access like this.

```
let ab = this.state.trends_1[0].start[0];
let cd = this.state.trends_1[0].start[1];
```

Comment: Right I didn't recognize trends_1 is an array :)